# Apache Rewrite to nginx syntax

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have this apache rewrite rule in a .htaccess file and want to transcribe it to nginx.

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$3?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can try new rule with Nginx:
http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx rewrite. What would the nginx equivelant of the above be?

Answer (score 0):

In general the apacahe stanza:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule <regeg> <target>
```

should be replaced with the nginx equivalent:

```
location ~* <regex> { try_files $uri $uri/ <target>; }
```

so in your case you need to add the following location to the nginx `server`-block for your site:

```
location ~* ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ { try_files $uri $uri/ /$3?$1=$2; }
```